# How do I add the last two values of a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

```
list_sum' :: (Num x) => [x] -> x
list_sum' [] = 0
list_sum' (y:ys) = y + list_sum' (ys)

main :: IO ()
main = do
      print(list_sum' [1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

Here I have some Haskell code that currently calculates the sum of all the items in the list. I am aiming to add all the items in the list that have a value greater than 5. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what should `list_sum' [1,2,3,4,5,6]` return? is it 6, or 11?

Comment: The specifications in the title are not in harmony with these in the question. In the title, you say "the last two" whereas in the question these are "a value greater than 5".

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different questions here so I will answer both.

**Question:** How do I add all elements in a list greater than 5?

**Answer:** You want the [`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter)  function.

```
list_sum' $ filter (> 5) [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

=> 13
```

**Question:** How do I add the last two element of a list?

**Answer:** This is harder as it is not easy to know where the end of the list is (a list in haskell can be infinitely long).

Here is how I might do it:

```
list_sum' $ take 2 $ reverse [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

=> 13
```